# Long tag names cause link to tag information page to be hidden

Tags: bug, tags, design, tag-autocomplete

When a long tag is shown in the tag autocomplete results, the button with the question mark, leading to the tag information page, is partially hidden behind the next column:

[image: tag autocomplete results with partially hidden button]

(tested in the latest Firefox on macOS Catalina)

Even longer tag names cause the button to be completely hidden, as this example by [@41686d6564 stands w. Palestine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344437/long-tag-names-cause-link-to-tag-information-page-to-be-hidden#comment1154026_344437):

[image: tag autocomplete results with completely hidden button]

Comment: Not just partially. It can disappear completely if the tag name is [long enough](https://i.imgur.com/hUU4lNX.png).

Comment: Note that the tag doesn't have to be long enough for the button to disappear. Buttons which are *partially* hidden can completely disappear if you type more characters in the text field (which causes the text to embolden, thus expanding the tag name to the right).

Comment: ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHxGs.png