# Too little space selecting long tags in custom question filter

Tags: bug, tags, custom-filters

This screenshot shows my first impression the new info button when creating a filter (on [RPG SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions)):

[image: tag filter problem]

There are two problems here:

- The top tag shown here has [11 questions, not 1](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-tabletop-united)
- The bottom tag makes the info button hide off the side of the dropdown

Can the box be made wider so that everything fits?

Comment: Or make tags break onto the next line when their too long.

Comment: Related: [Long tag names cause link to tag information page to be hidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344437/long-tag-names-cause-link-to-tag-information-page-to-be-hidden)